# Please Help me understanding this equation

Tags: algorithms, computational-complexity

I am preparing for my CS exams first year, I need help in understanding the below solution for given 
$$
T(n)=
\begin{cases}
3T(n-1),& \mbox{if }n>0\\
1,& \mbox{otherwise}
\end{cases}
$$
equation.

> solution:
>   $$T(n) = 3T(n-1)$$ $$T(n) = 3 ( 3T(n-2)) = 3^2T(n-2)$$  $$T(n)= 3^2(3T(n-3))$$ how are we getting this $(n-3)$ from $(n-2)?$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We know that $T(n) = 3T(n-1)$. But this is true for *all* $n$. So it must be true for $n - 2$, as well. So $T(n-2) = 3T((n - 2) - 1)$. Simplifying inside the $T$, we have $T(n-2) = 3T(n-3)$. Since $T(n) = 3^2T(n-2)$, substituting $T(n-2) = 3T(n-3)$ gives us $T(n) = 3^2(3T(n-3))$.

We can simplify one step further, to get $T(n) = 3^3T(n-3)$.

Comment: You might as well mention also that $\forall n \ge 0, T(n) = 3^n$.

Comment: Thanks so much Reese!!, It makes sense to me now.